# ASP.NET - Mobile Applications Development

Tags: asp.net, mobile

Dear All,
                 We are planning to develop Mobile Applications.

Would you please let me know the following information, if you have an idea.

- Merits and demerits when we use ASP.NET for Mobile Applications Development.
- Best reference book for ASP.NET Mobile Applications Development.

Many Thanks,
Regards,
Anupriya.

Comment: For Windows CE? Which OS are you aiming for?

Comment: Dear James,
                        I am new to Mobile applications development.

Would you please guide me on few details about building applications those run natively on mobile devices.  Which are the best languages to go for with respect to the current market needs.

Many Thanks, Regards, Anupriya.

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm not sure that I'm understanding your question correctly... When you develop a web application in ASP and host it on a server, both mobile devices and regular computers can use that application in their respective browsers.

It's important to realize the difference between a web application that can be accessed properly on a mobile device and an application that runs natively on a mobile device.

So, if you want to build an application that is accessible on mobile and desktop devices, then a web application is potentially a good choice.

The language you choose for your web application has no bearing on whether or not you will have success in allowing mobile users to access your application.

That being said, what you probably need is a good [intro ASP book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430226080) and (most importantly from your perspective) a [good book on mobile website development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596807783).

Comment: Dear Robert,
                         You are right.  Thank you very much for the details. 

Would you please also guide me on building applications those run natively on mobile devices.  Do you suggest .NET for this or which are the other best options to consider.

Many Thanks, Regards, Anupriya.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help.  The answer to your question is not easy on the surface.  First, which device do you want to develop for?  iPhone, android, Windows 7 phone?  All have pros and cons and this is an important decision that you need to make.  Once you decide, I recommend buying a book for developing on that platform and going through it.  If you let me know what you choose, I can help point you in the right direction.  Good luck!